# Subscribing to an OpenTok stream gives me the mirror image of the publisher view

Tags: android, opentok

I want to implement video calling feature using Opentok.

I followed the steps given in the [link](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/opentok-for-android/)

I'm getting the publisher view once the session is connected in receive stream i'm writing the code

```
subscriber = session.createSubscriber(subscriberView,stream);
subscriber.connect();
```

it gives the mirror image of publisher view 
how to get subscriber view

Answer (score 2):

Open `OpnTokConfig.java`

and set `SUBSCRIBE_TO_SELF` to false

// Subscribe to a stream published by this client. Set to false to subscribe
    // to other clients' streams only.

```
 public static final boolean SUBSCRIBE_TO_SELF = false;
```

This is whats causing you to show your own video

Answer (score 1):

When you subscribe to video streams, make sure that you are creating a new surfaceView to put the video in. If not, you would be overriding the same surfaceView with new subscribed feeds.

The reason why you are getting a mirror image of publisher view is because you subscribed to your own video, which is great because the subscribing worked. Good luck!